# How can i search into the whole array to find its key?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How do you find the key from a large array list like below in a fast/optimise way?

```
var error_constant_ENGLISH = {
  group0: {'xyz','1234'},

  group1: {'Temporarily Unavailable',
           'Invalid number',
           'You have reached the voice mail of P P P',
           'We are sorry then number you have dialed is not valid please try again',
           'Large sentences'},

  group2: {'abc','def large sentences'}
}

var error_constant_FRENCH = {
  group0: {'xyz','1234'},

  group1: {'Temporarily Unavailable',
           'Invalid number',
           'You have reached the voice mail of P P P',
           'We are sorry then number you have dialed is not valid please try again',
           'Large sentences'},

  group2: {'abc','def large sentences'}
}

// Assume: 
var language='ENGLISH';
var reason_phrase='Invalid number'
search_in_error(reason_phrase); 

// Expected output: group1
```

Comment: First of all make sure your data is valid. Right now it's not. You probably want arrays `['xyz','1234']`, not `{'xyz','1234'}`

Comment: YES - so its [] not { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such data structure it cannot be faster than O(n x m). Assuming that error groups were meant to be arrays.

```
function search_in_error(phrase){
    var errorGroup = window["error_constant_" + language],
        errors;
    for(var key in errorGroup){
        if (!errorGroup.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            continue;
        }
        errors = errorGroup[key];
        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++){
            if (errors[i] === phrase)
                return key;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fsd63jf2/

Answer (score 0):

This are not arrays but Objects!
Object enclosed with "{  }"

```
group1: {
    var1:'Temporarily Unavailable',
    var2:'Invalid number',
    var3:'Large sentences'
},
```

Arrays are enclosed with "[  ]" and only allow numeric Indexes 0,1,2,

```
group1: [
    'Temporarily Unavailable',
    'Invalid number',
    'Large sentences'
],
```

So if you change it into arrays you can use this

```
function search_in_error(errormessage, language){
    var myObj = self["error_constant_"+language];
    for(var name in myObj){
        var myArr = myObj[name];
        if(myArr.indexOf){ if(myArr.indexOf(errormessage)>-1){ return name; } }
        else{ for(var i=0; i<myArr.length; i++){ if(errormessage==myArr[i]){return name;} } }
    }
}
```

Call It like this:

```
search_in_error(reason_phrase, language);
```

> You have to correctly define the language object:

```
var error_constant_ENGLISH = {
    group1:[
        'aaaaa',
        'bbb'
    ],
    group2:[
        'Temporary Unavailable',
        'Invalid Number'
    ]
};
```

> Look Here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fede/597mzc91/9/

Comment: Getting error: `var error_en = {
  ['Temporary Unavailable'],
  ['Invalid Number']
};`

Comment: instead of group1 or group2, can i simply get the key id? 0, or 1 or 2?

Comment: Sorry, I tested it and corrected some errors... it works now. try again please...